# telnet to zimbra 110 port failed from ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, telnet

We are using Thunderbird on Ubuntu 12.04, Windowx XP and Windows 7.

Telnet to 25 port done successful from both Windows and Ubuntu clients.

When we telnet to mail server port 110 from any Windows telnet it is done successfully.

But from Ubuntu I am unable to telnet mail server port 110.

```
telnet mail2.mydomain.net 110

Trying 175.100.185.230....
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that pop3 service is up with `sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 110`

If it is up, then there's probably something in between is blocking port 110.